# Photo Sphere and Panorama are not available in Google Camera app

Tags: google-camera

Recently Google launched a new camera app named [Google Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.GoogleCamera). Looking it's features, I found it has Photo Sphere and Panorama options. But when I installed it on my Moto G device it doesn't have both of those options. Only Lens Blur, (normal) Camera and Video options are available. See this:

[image]

What is the reason behind it? Or is there any setting I have to activate?

Comment: FYI: Moto G's stock camera app has a Panorama option.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Moto G **doesn't have a Gyroscope Sensor** (but it has an accelerometer). That's why Moto G didn't get the Photosphere option.

Actually, Panorama doesn't require a gyroscope. While there are obviously ways to do panoramas without a gyroscope. It looks like they use the same engine as Photosphere to do the panoramas. So the app also lacks Panorama.

**[Source Thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2549270)**
**[Google Camera G+ Thread](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+android/posts/86JHD2mWW6k)**

Answer (score 3):

There are several reasons for this, but it is mainly due to hardware limitations, Photosphere and panorama stitch together multiple images at the pixel level and require some pretty processor intensive work. Some users also mention that the lack of a gyroscope sensor as a possible reason.

I have googled and found at least 3 sources that corroborate this. Sorry but it looks like your out of luck.

http://www.engadget.com/2014/04/16/google-stock-camera-app-photo-sphere-lens-blur/
https://www.yahoo.com/tech/the-best-features-of-googles-new-android-camera-app-83124330305.html
http://www.slashgear.com/moto-g-google-play-edition-hands-on-vs-motorolas-g-15313328/

Answer (score 1):

You can take panorama photos on the Motorola Moto G, if you use the Motorola Camera that was preinstalled. There is an option to take a panorama shot when you swipe from left to right in the camera interface. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this helped. But I already mentioned that in my comment.

Comment: @hims056 That's why you should always edit your post when you want to add extra information. Comments are for querying posts and seeking clarification, not for adding information.